# Can I update my dual-handle faucet without replacing the entire thing?

Tags: bathroom, bathroom-fixtures, diy-vs-pro

I want to replace these rotting hot/cold handles. Hoping it’s easy enough to do myself. The base part that’s rotting out, is it necessary and easy to remove? Thinking I want to remove it and not replace with another base that would age similarly and rot, most handles I see don’t have that separate piece. With no background in plumbing should I even attempt this? Simply want to order something vintage and pop off old and pop new on [image]

Comment: Are you able to remove the top and photograph the base?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the base is either an intrinsic part of the faucet (ie, it threads onto the faucet body and holds it in place) or it’s a spacer that allows the body to be nutted into place or it’s decorative.

Take off the knob and find out.

My guess is that you’ll be replacing everything, which really isn’t that bad, as new will look good and work well for years to come.

If it’s just the knob getting replaced, count the splines… that’ll be handy when you shop.